# Difference in Windows Properties dialogs for folders

Tags: windows, dialog

In Windows, there seems to be two separate versions of the Properties dialog (displayed when a folder is right-clicked and Properties is selected from the context menu):

[image]

The one on the left seems to be the default one, but sometimes the one on the right gets displayed.  Is there a rhyme or reason for the difference?

I am using Windows 10 Build 1909.

Comment: I don't know any solid proof. But for the right case, the "Location" tab is a feature for Windows Shell aka. File Explorer with which user can change the location of that folder. More info here `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` registry.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not "separate versions" it is simply that the one on the right has an extra "Locations" tab which is causing the tab bar to overflow on to two lines.

The "Locations" tab is visible on special folders, such as the user "Documents" folder, and allows the folder location to be move or otherwise changed.

Comment: Much appreciated. Regards.